# What task can I append to Task?

Tags: c#, concurrency, task-parallel-library, task, async-await

I saw this code:

```
[HttpGet]  
public async Task OperationAsync()  
{   
    await Task.Delay(2000);  
}
```

...in tip #7 [here](http://blog.developers.ba/8-ways-improve-asp-net-web-api-performance/), and thought I would try it out. I changed this code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Deliveries/Count")]
public int GetCountOfDeliveryRecords()
{
    return NRBQService.GetNRBQEntity(); 
}
```

...to this:

```
// [HttpGet] unnecessary when method name begins with "Get"
[Route("api/Deliveries/Count")] 
public async Task<int> GetCountOfDeliveryRecords()
{
    return await Task.NRBQService.GetNRBQEntity();
}
```

...but get, "*'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for NRBQService'*"

So what should I do to get it compile/work?

Comment: `Delay` is a static method on the `Task` class. `NRBQService` is not. What you're probably looking for is an equivalent of `NRBQService.GetNRBQEntityAsync`.

Comment: `return await Task.Run(()=>NRBQService.GetNRBQEntity());` But how do you think it will help you?

Comment: @EZI: Not recommended on ASP.NET.

Comment: Are you having performance issues and trying to fix them? Because this is very very unlikely to fix anything. That tip in general should come with a whole ton of caveats. Async is good, but its not doing anything magical - it just potentially frees up threads. This is usually useful when using libraries designed for async - typically requests to other web services and maybe heavy duty file processing.

Comment: As a matter of fact, that entire list is a bit naive. Every single item on there should come with a boatload of caveats, enough that each can be an article in itself. The first thing that any optimization job needs is profiling to figure out what exactly is causing the issue. Then work at unblocking that. Generic "tips and tricks" are likely to result in non-meaningful micro-optimizations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only await a `Task` or `Task<T>` (also other awaitables, but its unlikely you need to use one). `Task.Delay` is an asynchronous method that returns a `Task`. That allows you to write:

```
await Task.Delay(2000);
```

`NRBQService.GetNRBQEntity` is a method that returns an `int`, and so can't be awaited. You would need to create an asynchronous method that returns `Task<int>` like this:

```
public async Task<int> NRBQService.GetNRBQEntityAsync()
{
    // ...
}
```

And you could use it like that:

```
[Route("api/Deliveries/Count")] 
public async Task<int> GetCountOfDeliveryRecords()
{
    return await NRBQService.GetNRBQEntity();
}
```

Comment: Interesting trivia - [you can actually await anything that has a GetAwaiter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx) method...and extension methods count! So it technically would be possible for the OP to await an int, just pointless.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer true. That's why whenever i say "you can only await a task" I feel the need to add 2 paragraphs explaining why that's not true although you should act as though it is.